# Printed <tab> on pressing the tab key

Tags: tab-characters

It's not easy to articulate the question, as I touched something I don't understand. I am using a vim extension of VS-CODE.

I pressed something, that turned my next pressed key, into a literal, namely `<tab>`.

What is this functionality called? How can I tap it again?

Comment: this is vs-code? might be not the best resource here.

Comment: Usually `<C-v>` is literal insert